# Вылетает приложение при попытке передачи значения в потоке

Tags: java, android

Я сделал приложение-парсер и написал функцию `cleaner`, которая должна убирать первые слова, если они есть в "чёрном списке", но при попытке передачи возвращаемого этой функцией значения приложение вылетает. Что делать? Код и логи ошибки прилагаю ниже:

Код:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements MyRecyclerViewAdapter.ItemClickListener {

MyRecyclerViewAdapter adapter;

public Elements content;
public ArrayList<String> titleList = new ArrayList<>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    new NewThread().execute();
    new NewThread().execute();
    RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.rv_list);
    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
    adapter = new MyRecyclerViewAdapter(this, titleList);
    adapter.setClickListener(this);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "You clicked " + adapter.getItem(position) + " on row number " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

public class NewThread extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    String cleaner(String a){
        String source = a;
        String result = " ";
        ArrayList<String> arr = new ArrayList<>();
        arr.add(source);

        for(String retrival: source.split(" ")){
            arr.add(retrival);
        }

        arr.remove(0);

        for(int i = 0; i<arr.size(); i++){
            if(arr.get(i).equals("Россия")||arr.get(i).equals("Екатеринбург")){
                arr.remove(i);
            }
            result+=arr.get(i);
        }

        return result;
    }
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg) {
        Document doc;

        try{
            doc= Jsoup.connect("https://www.znak.com/?&%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B3%20%D0%BC%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%B5").get();
            content = doc.select(".pub");

            for (Element headline : doc.getElementsByTag("h5")) {
                Log.d("parse", headline.text());
            }

            titleList.clear();
            for(Element contents: content){
                titleList.add(cleaner(contents.text()));
            }

        }catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
}
```

---

Логи:

```
04-25 20:10:35.187 20033-20051/com.example.max.recyclerviewtesting E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
Process: com.example.max.recyclerviewtesting, PID: 20033
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:353)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:383)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:252)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:271)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:245)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
 Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 6, Size: 6
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:437)
    at com.example.max.recyclerviewtesting.MainActivity$NewThread.cleaner(MainActivity.java:73)
    at com.example.max.recyclerviewtesting.MainActivity$NewThread.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:98)
    at com.example.max.recyclerviewtesting.MainActivity$NewThread.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:53)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:333)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:245) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636) 
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764) 
04-25 20:10:35.412 20033-20054/com.example.max.recyclerviewtesting D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa3c88340: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xabb1ba30)
04-25 20:10:35.446 20033-20038/com.example.max.recyclerviewtesting I/zygote: Do partial code cache collection, code=60KB, data=45KB
04-25 20:10:35.449 20033-20038/com.example.max.recyclerviewtesting I/zygote: After code cache collection, code=60KB, data=45KB
    Increasing code cache capacity to 256KB
```

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы безопасно удалять элементы из коллекции в цикле, нужно использовать `Iterator`

```
Iterator<String> iterator = arr.iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    String string = iterator.next();
    if (string.equals("Россия") || string.equals("Екатеринбург")) {
        iterator.remove();
        result += string;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Огромное спасибо katso. Его код отлично работал, но выводил немного не тот результат. Вот исправленная версия:

```
 Iterator<String> iterator = arr.iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {

            String string = iterator.next();

            if (string.equals("Россия") || string.equals("Екатеринбург")) {
                iterator.remove();

            }else{
                result += string+" ";
            }

        }
```